# Получить данные в двух столбцах

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица с сообщениями, где `sender_id` указывает кто отослал, а `recipient_id` указывает кто принял, и есть таблица `users`, которая содержит инфу о `id` пользователя и его имя.  Я хочу вывести все имена, кто кому писал (последовательно).

Я получил такой код, для получения пользователя, который отправил сообщение, но как добавить пользователя который принял?

```
SELECT name 
FROM users 
JOIN (
     SELECT messages.sender_id AS id 
     FROM messages
  ) AS N 
WHERE N.id = users.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если у вас сообщения 2 раза связаны с пользователями, просто два раза приджойньте таблицу пользователей.

```
SELECT DISTINCT us.name as sender
       , ur.name as recipient
FROM messages as m
INNER JOIN users AS us ON (us.id = m.sender_id)
INNER JOIN users AS ur ON (ur.id = m.recipient_id)
```